# how to proxy RMI call with nginx

Tags: nginx, rmi

does anyone know how to proxy RMI with nginx?

Nginx v1.9+

my current nginx server block.

```
stream  {
upstream QA1{
   server 10.168.85.39:30900;
}
upstream QA2 {
    server 10.51.67.17:30900;
}



 server {
    listen       30900;
    proxy_pass QA1;
 }
server {
    listen       30901;
    proxy_pass QA2;
}
```

}

I'm getting a timeout error on the client-side

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to convert RMI to HTTP, and proxy HTTP with Nginx.